# Using Python Dict to Send Emails with Specific Attachments

Tags: python, outlook, attachment, win32com

I have a python dictionary:

```
df.set_index('EMAIL').to_dict()['ID'] 
   
email_group = {'test1@test.com': 'ID1.xlsx',
               'test2@test.com': 'ID2.xlsx',
               'test3@test.com': 'ID3.xlsx'
                   }
```

**Expected Result:** I want to attach `ID1.xlsx` to the first email address and send, `ID2.xlsx` to the 2nd email address and send, and finally `ID3.xlsx` to the 3rd email address and send.

The following code produces an error "name 'file' is not defined". What am I missing to get the expected result above?

```
class EmailsSender:
        def __init__(self):
            self.outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    
        def send_email(self, to_email_address, attachment_path):
            mail = self.outlook.CreateItem(0)
            mail.To = to_email_address
            mail.Subject = 'Report'
            mail.Body = """Report is attached."""
            if attachment_path:
                mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment_path)
            mail.Send()
    
        def send_emails(self, email_group, attachment_path=None):
            for email, file in email_group.items():
                self.send_email(email, attachment_path + file)
    
    attachment_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Test'
    email_sender = EmailsSender()
    email_sender.send_emails(email_group, attachment_path + file)
```

Comment: what does the object `email_group` contain? Also as the error suggests, what is `file` ?

Comment: Apologies - I corrected the question. email_group is the dict of email addresses and corresponding attachments. File is the file that is found in the desktop folder.

Comment: Which line causes the error? I assume `email_sender.send_emails(email_group, attachment_path + file)`. What are you trying to do here? There is no variable named `file` when this line executes.

Comment: I was trying to use the dict 'email_group' with the email address and filename to attach the correct XLSX file to the correct email address and send the emails out. I've responded to your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
email_sender.send_emails(email_group, attachment_path + file)
```

to

```
email_sender.send_emails(email_group, attachment_path)
```

The interpret complains because `file` isn't declared here.

Comment: I made the change you suggested and received the following error: "(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct.', None, 0, -2147024894), None)"

Comment: @Mark the error is very clear about what you need to do

Comment: I honestly cannot figure this out. I've tried to edit the attachment path to include \*.xlsx with no luck. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Mark You should debug your code by adding `print()` statements. For example, in `send_emails()` add `print(attachment_path + file)`. To see the actual path you are trying to attach to the email. Check this output very closely for misspellings or missing slashes. You should also checkout the `os.path.join()` method to ensure that slashes are added correctly. If you still need help, please post a new question since my answer here resolves the question you originally posted on this page.